# Django: Sort and filter rows by specific many to one value

Tags: django, postgresql

In the provided schema I would like to sort `Records` by a specific `Attribute` of the record.  I'd like to do this in native Django.

Example:

Query all `Records` (regardless of `Attribute.color`), but sort by `Attribute.value` where `Attribute.color` is `'red'`.  Obviously `Records` missing a `'red`' `Attribute` can't be sorted, so they could be just interpreted as `NULL` or sent to the end.

Each `Record` is guaranteed to have one or zero of an `Attribute` of a particular color (enforced by `unique_together`).  Given this is a one to many relationship, a `Record` can have `Attributes` of more than` one color.

```
class Record(Model):
    pass

class Attribute(Model):
    color = CharField() # **See note below
    value = IntegerField()
    record = ForeignKey(Record)

    class Meta:
       unique_together = (('color', 'record'),)
```

I will also need to filter `Records` by `Attribute.value` and `Attribute.color` as well.

I'm open to changing the schema, but the schema above seems to be the simplest to represent what I need to model.

How can I:

- Query all `Records` where it has an `Attribute.color` of `'red'` and, say, an `Attribute.value` of `10`
- Query all `Records` and sort by the `Attribute.value` of the associated `Attribute` where `Attribute.color` is `'red'`.

** I've simplified it above -- in reality the `color` field would be a `ForeignKey` to an `AttributeDefinition`, but I think that's not important right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this would work:

```
record_ids = Attribute.objects.filter(color='red', value=10).values_list('record', flat=True)
```

and

```
record_ids = Attribute.objects.filter(color='red').order_by('value').values_list('record', flat=True)
```

That will give you IDs of records. Then, you can do this:

```
records = Record.objects.filter(id__in=record_ids)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah, yes...I keep thinking of it as a Record.objects.filter() .... Will try it tomorrow.

Comment: One problem I see is the order_by example doesn't include other colors...

Comment: ....is there any way to sort by more than one color...?  red, then blue?

Comment: @rrauenza yes there is: `.filter(color__in=['red', 'blue'])`

Comment: Ah, no - it needs to be like order by (red, greeen) where it sorts by one first and then the other.  It’s ok for now - I’ll wait until the users ask for that and then figure it out.  Maybe sort client side.